# Existence of weak solution to $-\Delta u =0$, $u|_{\Gamma_1} = g$ and $u_{\Gamma_2} = 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with $\partial\Omega = \Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2$ a union of disjoint sets.

Let $g \in H^s(\Gamma_1)$ and consider
$$-\Delta u = 0 \text{ on $\Omega$}$$
$$u|_{\Gamma_1} = g$$
$$u|_{\Gamma_2} = 0.$$

How does one define and prove existence of weak solution for such a problem? Are there any references?

What I find in the literature when the boundary is disjoint is that one part of the boundary is given Dirichlet condition and the other is given Neumann condition but I don't want this.

Comment: Are you sure you need the boundary condition to be $H^s$? As I recall you only need it to be $L^2$, which $h := g \cdot 1_{\Gamma_1} + 0 \cdot 1_{\Gamma_2}$ is. But maybe there are some manifold issues that I don't know about (my knowledge is really confined to bounded open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.) If you really *do* need the boundary condition to be $H^s$ then you may have a  problem, because if $h$ has a jump then it may not be $H^s$.

Comment: @Ian I think it's not a problem, all I am saying is that my data $g$ is very nice. I don't claim it's a necessary.

Comment: Gotcha. But now I realized I still made a mistake (even in the open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ case, where we have no manifold technicalities). Since the trace operator isn't onto, there is some question as to whether there is a $H^1$ function with the desired trace. I think you will be OK provided your boundary condition is at least $H^{1/2}$, because I think the trace is onto $H^{1/2}$ (when coming from $H^1$).

Comment: @Ian You're right that trace is surjective onto $H^{\frac 12}$. However the indicator function is not that smooth so I think the approach of defining $h$ doesn't work..

Comment: If your trace is not in $H^{1/2}$ then there is no $H^1$ function with that trace, so your notion of solution will need to be weaker still.

Comment: well my $g \in H^{\frac 12}$, but your approach of using $h:= g 1_{\Gamma_1}$ won't work I think since $h \notin H^{\frac 12}$. So another approach is needed.

Comment: That's what I mean; if that $h$ is not $H^{1/2}$ then your notion of solution is weaker than that in, say, Lax-Milgram, since your "solution" cannot have  a trace which is the same as your boundary condition. So you need a different formulation than the classic one. The fast track to the alternate formulation that I know uses tools from probability; it writes the solution to the Dirichlet problem as $E[f(X_\tau)]$ where $f$ is the boundary function, $\tau$ is the first hitting time of the boundary, and $X$ is Brownian motion (in this case Brownian motion on the manifold).

Comment: (Cont.) This can be reasonably justified in the case when $f$ is $C^2$ by using Ito's formula, and then now that you have the form (which still makes sense provided that $X_\tau$ is at the interface with probability zero), you can try to justify it under weaker regularity hypotheses.

Comment: This also tells you that it matters how much $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ are "wrapped up in each other". If, say, they are two halves of a circle, then there's really no problem, because the two points where $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ meet are negligible.

Comment: Hmm. In my case they are the opposite faces of a cylinder.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain a little more? What exactly is the domain, the inside of the cylinder or the surface of the cylinder?

Comment: Let $\Omega = M \times (0,1)$ where $M$ is a compact closed manifold. So $\partial\Omega = M \times \{0\} \cup M \times \{1\}$. So it is like a cylinder.

Comment: Are $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ the caps (copies of $ M $) then? If so then there should be no concern about regularity.

Comment: Well yes they are copies of $M$ I guess. But they are compltely disjoint from each other so I'm not sure of the regularity. Think of a tube of Pringles, then $\Gamma_1$ is the lid and $\Gamma_2$ is the base.

Comment: That's what I figured. Yes, that means that there is no need to be concerned about the indicator function. It is exactly as regular as $g$ on the boundary because the two parts of the boundary cannot "communicate". So the $h$ I wrote down before is indeed $H^s(\Gamma)$. So at least from the standpoint of the trace theorem, you should be OK provided $g$ is $H^{1/2}$.

Comment: Hmm. Basically we need the $H^{\frac 12}$ seminorm of $h$ to be finite. But this is $|h|_{H^{\frac 12}(\partial\Omega)} = |g|_{H^{\frac 12}(\Gamma_1)} < \infty$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: That's right. This wouldn't necessarily work if $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ had any shared boundary, but they don't.

Comment: OK thanks. You can post an answer if you want.